# Customer Info Form sent to .txt file on desktop via button click

Tags: vb.net

Good evening,

I am attempting to finish this last little bit of my VB.net project for school.  It's the good ol' pizza ordering system.  After the welcome screen the user is prompted to enter first name/last name/email and then click submit (if they leave any box empty it will pop up w/ msgbox).  I need to send the information that is input into textbox1, textbox2, and textbox3 into a .txt file on the desktop if possible.
Here is the code

```
Public Class CustomerInfo

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter Your Information")
            ' Forces user to input something in to all three boxes before being allowed to proceed
            'Prompts user to complete form with a message box.
            'Once information is complete, clicking the submit button will close this form and open the Selection Form.
            Dim desktopPath As String =
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            Dim fileName As String = "customer.txt"
            Dim fullPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(desktopPath, fileName)
            IO.File.AppendAllLines(fullPath, {"textbox1.text & textbox2.text & textbox3.text"})

        else
        Selection.Show()
        Me.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
```

I attempted to upload a screenshot of the windows form, but am new to the forum.  It's very basic, text boxes 1, 2, and 3 with a "Submit" button below them.
Thanks in advance for any assistance provided.

Kyle

Comment: Are you getting any type of error?

Comment: So is the file not being created? If so see what MessageBox.Show(fullPath) brings up or watch it in debug to make sure the path is correct.

Comment: Also you're not removing trailing spaces when you validate the textboxes. So if the textbox only has one or more spaces in it then TextBox1.Text = "" will be false. Use TextBox1.Text.Trim = "" instead.